# Can I use a Skyrim Special Edition save in Skyrim?

Tags: pc, the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I started a new game over the festive holidays, but started with Skyrim Special Edition. What I didn't realise is that this version doesn't support free mods, such as SkyUI. As the 'Mods' menu item takes me to the Bethesda mod store.

Is it possible for me to copy my Skyrim Special Edition save into Skyrim and play it there with mods?

Google searches have led me to understand that you can take a Skyrim save into Special Edition, but I can't find mention of the opposite way around.

Comment: What platform are you playing on? SSE surely has more mods available than oldrim if you play on PC.

Comment: [SkyUI](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/12604) do support SSE edition though. The mods menu is just for "official"(ish) mods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Google searches have led me to understand that you can take a Skyrim save into Special Edition, but I can't find mention of the opposite way around.

You are correct in that you can import a save from LE to SE.

Unfortunately you cannot do it the other way round.

https://www.reddit.com/r/skyrim/comments/5f8289/can_i_transfer_skyrim_special_edition_save_to/

https://www.reddit.com/r/skyrim/comments/7jp295/moving_skyrim_special_edition_save_files_to/